# How i can find my pdf file on android phone

Tags: java, android, android-file

I've created an app where I assumed an ID opens a pdf file, but as it is now

```
pdfFile File = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () "/ storage/sdcard0 /" + item.getID () + ". pdf ")
```

so I located it in myself on the phone, but how can I throw it into the app so I can share it with pdf files? Have tried to make a `assets` under the res, but can not see where it is on your phone so `/ storage/sdcard0 /` can be changed to the location

Comment: You probably don't want the spaces in your file path.

Answer (score 0):

Please give some more details -
Do you want to check the file existence and take necessary action ? then you can proceed as follow-

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory () "/ storage/sdcard0 /" + item.getID () + ". pdf ");
 if(file.exists())
 {
  // do what you want
 }
```